# AstroJS contact form with Nodemailer

Tags: nodemailer, astrojs

I'm new to Node and struggling to use Nodemailer.

in scr/pages I have a contact_us.astro file.

```
---
import Layout from '../layouts/Layout.astro';
import Header from '../components/Header.astro';
import Footer from '../components/Footer.astro';

const errors = { username: "", email: "", message: "" };
if (Astro.request.method === "POST") {
  try {
    const data = await Astro.request.formData();
    const name = data.get("username");
    const email = data.get("email");
    const message = data.get("message");
    if (typeof name !== "string" || name.length < 1) {
      errors.username += "Please enter a username. ";
    }
    if (typeof email !== "string") {
      errors.email += "Email is not valid. ";
    }
    if (typeof message !== "string") {
      errors.message += "Please enter a message";
    }
    const hasErrors = Object.values(errors).some(msg => msg)
    if (!hasErrors) {
      console.log('button pressed')
      //return Astro.redirect("/team");

      const payload = {
      name: name,
      email: email,
      message: message
      };
      fetch("../lib/nodemailer", {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json"
          },
          body: JSON.stringify(payload)
      }).then(response => response.json())
          .then(data => {
              alert(data.message);
          })
          .catch(error => {
              console.error(error);
          });
   }
  } catch (error) {
    if (error instanceof Error) {
      console.error(error.message);
    }
  }
}

---

<Layout title="Meet the Madini Minerals Team">
    <Header/>
  <div class="page-banner">
    <div class="banner-images">
      <img src="/contact_us/contact_banner.jpg" alt="Banner 1">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content-container">
    <div class="right-content-mustard">
      <div class="text-button-container">
        <p class="h1 h1-white">For any queries<br>contact us</p>
        <a href=#start-text"></a><button class="custom-button">read more</button></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content-image">
      <img src="/homepage/contact_us.jpg" alt="Contact Us Image" class="about-image"> 
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="body-container body-container-small" id="start-text">
  <h1 class="h1">Contact Us</h1>
  
  <form method="POST">
    <label>
      Username:
      <input type="text" name="username" />
    </label>
    {errors.username && <p>{errors.username}</p>}
    <label>
      Email:
      <input type="email" name="email" required />
    </label>
    {errors.email && <p>{errors.email}</p>}
    <label>
      Message:
      <input type="text" name="message" />
    </label>
    {errors.message && <p>{errors.message}</p>}
    <button>Send</button>
  </form>
</script>

</div>
    <Footer/>
</Layout>
```

In scr/lib/ I have nodemailer.ts which is my end point

```
import nodemailer from 'nodemailer';
let email = import.meta.env.EMAIL
let password = import.meta.env.EMAIL_PASSWORD

console.log(password)
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: "smtp.ledimo.co.za",
    auth: {
        user: email,
        pass: password
    }
});

export async function post({ request }) {
    const data = await request.json();
    const mailOptions = {
        from: "joemmalatesta1@gmail.com",
        to: "joemmalatesta@gmail.com",
        subject: 'New message from your website',
        html: `<p><strong>Name:</strong>${data.name}</p>
               <p><strong>Email:</strong>${data.email}</p>
               <p><strong>Message:</strong>${data.message}</p>`,
    };

    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {

        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
        }
    });

    let payload = {
        message: "Server received your message!"
    }
    return {
        body: JSON.stringify(payload)
    };
}
```

When I submit the form I get the following error:

TypeError: Failed to parse URL from ../lib/nodemailer
at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11576:11) {
[cause]: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_URL]: Invalid URL

Answer (score 0):

// nodemailer.ts

```
    import nodemailer from "nodemailer";

    interface emailFunctionProps {
    email: string;
    html: string;
    subject: string;
    text: string;
   }

    // SMTP (sending) server details
    const smtpServer = "smtp.titan.email";
    const smtpPort = 587;

    // IMAP (receiving) server details
    const imapServer = "imap.titan.email";
    const imapPort = 993;

    async function sendEmail(props: emailFunctionProps) {
      let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      host: smtpServer,
      port: smtpPort,
      auth: {
      user: import.meta.env.OUTLOOK_EMAIL,
      pass: import.meta.env.OUTLOOK_PASSWORD,
    },
  });

     // Message object
     let message = {
      from: import.meta.env.OUTLOOK_EMAIL,
      to: props.email,
      subject: props.subject,
      text: props.text,
      html: props.html,
      };

      let info = await transporter.sendMail(message);
      console.log("Message sent successfully as %s", info.messageId);

       console.log({ info });
       return info;
     }

      export { sendEmail };
```

//inside contact_us.astro file

```
   if (Astro.request.method === "POST") {
  try {
    const data = await Astro.request.formData();
    const name = data.get("username");
    const email = data.get("email");
    const message = data.get("message");


       const payload = {
      name: name,
      email: email,
      message: message
      };

    await sendEmail({
        email: "email@gmail.com",
        html: `<p>${JSON.stringify(payload)}</p>`,
        subject: "hello",
        text: "hello",
      });

}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**